# File to byte array with .mov

Tags: java, file, arrays

I need to convert a file to a byte array, but I can't do it with a .mov file (1.32 Gb).  The method works fine with small .txt files and JPEG images, but when I try to do it with the MOV file I can't. I just get a NullPointerException.

code:

```
public byte[] fileToByteArray(File file){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    InputStream fis = null;
    try{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        int read;
        while((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1){
            baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error: 1");
    }finally{
        try{
            if(baos != null){
                baos.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: 2");
        }
        try{
            if(fis != null){
                fis.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error: 3");
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: *Where* do you get a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Why do you need to convert a 1.32GB file to a byte array at all? This is a very bad idea. You should find a way of dealing with it as a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
return baos.toByteArray();
```

You're *unconditionally* dereferencing `baos`... even though it will still be null if this line throws an exception:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)file.length()];
```

I suspect that line *has* thrown an exception (out of memory, at a guess)... but due to your exception handling strategy of "catch all exceptions, print them out and ignore them" you're keeping going when you shouldn't.

The immediate fix to this is to only catch the exceptions you *really* want to catch - which should almost certainly only be `IOException` in this case, *if anything*. In fact, I probably wouldn't use any `catch` clauses in the code you've written at all, other than possibly on the `close` code. (You don't want an exception in `close` to obscure an exception elsewhere. If you're using Java 7, use the try-with-resources statement to make all of this easier to start with.)

"Handling" exceptions in the way you're doing is a very bad idea - you're basically saying that you want to proceed regardless of what's gone wrong, and that just makes one error lead to another if you're lucky, or if you're unlucky you end up making bad state changes, e.g. overwriting good data with bad, without even realizing it.

Now as for the *bigger* problem - you're trying to allocate an enormous array, and I suspect you haven't told the JVM to use that much memory. You'll need to start it with something like:

```
java -Xmx3G ...
```

... assuming you're on a 64-bit JVM which is happy to use that much memory.

Comment: @CodingGuy maybe try incrementally reading parts of it... you really shouldn't want to keep it all in memory at a single time. You could even try memory-mapping the file if need be. Re-evaluate what your goal is.

Comment: @CodingGuy: I've given you all the information you need to improve your code. As oldrinb says, reading a file that size into memory is generally a bad idea to start with, mind you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Accept the solution and upvote. Read FAQ for more details

Answer (score 0):

1.32 GB is roughly *2^30.4* bytes. An `OutOfMemoryError` will more than likely be thrown at this line:

> ```
> byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)file.length()];
> ```

As a result, the code flow jumps to the exception handler (it will try to print `"Error: 1"`, which *may* or *may **not*** work in this case). As a result, when the code flow reaches the `finally` block, `baos` is still `null`, hence your `NullPointerException`.

The solution I'd advise is to **not try to read a 1.32 GB file into memory**... at least like that.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not reading it in chunks of say 4K/8K/16K byte-array ? In that way you will never run out of memory. I have copied as huge as 20GB files in this way over network.

Comment: That is also what i'm going to do now that i know what the problem was

Comment: Good. That should fix the problem. 512MB of Xmx option is what I used for 20GB file copy. So it should be able to copy your file without changing memory settings

Comment: I can't get over that the answer was so simple